Having issues fetching data from Mailchimp in Sveltekit App
I've successfully connected to the Mailchimp API, but I can't figure out why the data doesn't want to display on the page.
I've spent the last two days on this issue. The API Key is valid, and the Mailchimp NPM package is up to date.
On the +page.svelte page, no data is displayed in the console, so for some reason the async load function is not being accessed via this component, and I have no idea why.
Both files are in a folder called API
Route > API > +page.server.js and +page.svelte
Here is my +page.server.js code
import mailchimp from '@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing';

const apiKey = import.meta.env.VITE_MAILCHIMP_API_KEY;

if (!apiKey) {
  throw new Error('API key is not defined. Please check your .env file.');
}

const serverPrefix = apiKey.split('-')[1];
mailchimp.setConfig({
  apiKey: apiKey,
  server: serverPrefix,
});

export async function load() {
  try {
    const campaignsResponse = await mailchimp.campaigns.list({ count: 10 });
    console.log('Campaigns Response:', campaignsResponse);

    const campaigns = campaignsResponse.campaigns || [];
    const campaignData = [];

    for (const campaign of campaigns) {
      const campaignReportResponse = await mailchimp.reports.get(campaign.id);
      const reports = campaignReportResponse;

      const reportData = {
        send_time: campaign.send_time,
        campaign_id: campaign.id,
        campaign_title: campaign.settings.title,
        subject_line: campaign.settings.subject_line,
        emails_sent: reports.emails_sent || 0,
        abuse_reports: reports.abuse_reports || 0,
        unsubscribed: reports.unsubscribed || 0,
        unsubscribe_rate: reports.emails_sent ? (reports.unsubscribed / reports.emails_sent) : 0,
        hard_bounces: reports.bounces?.hard_bounces || 0,
        soft_bounces: reports.bounces?.soft_bounces || 0,
        bounces: (reports.bounces?.hard_bounces || 0) + (reports.bounces?.soft_bounces || 0),
        syntax_errors: reports.bounces?.syntax_errors || 0,
        forwards_count: reports.forwards?.forwards_count || 0,
        forwards_opens: reports.forwards?.forwards_opens || 0,
        opens_total: reports.opens?.opens_total || 0,
        unique_opens: reports.opens?.unique_opens || 0,
        open_rate: reports.opens?.open_rate || 0,
        last_open: reports.opens?.last_open || null,
        clicks_total: reports.clicks?.clicks_total || 0,
        unique_clicks: reports.clicks?.unique_clicks || 0,
        unique_subscriber_clicks: reports.clicks?.unique_subscriber_clicks || 0,
        click_rate: reports.clicks?.click_rate || 0,
      };

      campaignData.push(reportData);
    }

    console.log('Formatted Campaign Data:', campaignData);

    return {
      props: {
        campaigns: campaignData,
      },
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching Mailchimp data:', error.response ? error.response.body : error.message);
    
    return {
      props: {
        campaigns: [],
      },
    };
  }
}

+page.svelte
<script>
    export let campaigns = [];
    console.log(campaigns); 
</script>

{#if campaigns.length > 0}
    {#each campaigns as campaign}
        <div class="campaign">
            <h2>{campaign.campaign_title}</h2>
            <p><strong>Subject Line:</strong> {campaign.subject_line}</p>
            <p><strong>Sent Time:</strong> {new Date(campaign.send_time).toLocaleString()}</p>
            <p><strong>Emails Sent:</strong> {campaign.emails_sent}</p>
            <p><strong>Abuse Reports:</strong> {campaign.abuse_reports}</p>
            <p><strong>Unsubscribed:</strong> {campaign.unsubscribed}</p>
            <p><strong>Unsubscribe Rate:</strong> {(campaign.unsubscribe_rate * 100).toFixed(2)}%</p>
            <p><strong>Hard Bounces:</strong> {campaign.hard_bounces}</p>
            <p><strong>Soft Bounces:</strong> {campaign.soft_bounces}</p>
            <p><strong>Total Bounces:</strong> {campaign.bounces}</p>
            <p><strong>Syntax Errors:</strong> {campaign.syntax_errors}</p>
            <p><strong>Forwards Count:</strong> {campaign.forwards_count}</p>
            <p><strong>Forwards Opens:</strong> {campaign.forwards_opens}</p>
            <p><strong>Opens Total:</strong> {campaign.opens_total}</p>
            <p><strong>Unique Opens:</strong> {campaign.unique_opens}</p>
            <p><strong>Open Rate:</strong> {(campaign.open_rate * 100).toFixed(2)}%</p>
            <p><strong>Last Open:</strong> {campaign.last_open ? new Date(campaign.last_open).toLocaleString() : 'N/A'}</p>
            <p><strong>Clicks Total:</strong> {campaign.clicks_total}</p>
            <p><strong>Unique Clicks:</strong> {campaign.unique_clicks}</p>
            <p><strong>Unique Subscriber Clicks:</strong> {campaign.unique_subscriber_clicks}</p>
            <p><strong>Click Rate:</strong> {(campaign.click_rate * 100).toFixed(2)}%</p>
            <a href={campaign.archive_url} target="_blank">View Campaign</a>
        </div>
    {/each}
{:else}
    <p>No campaigns found.</p>
{/if}


That is (still) not how data loading works in current SvelteKit versions, read the docs please.
The returned object does not need a props wrapper and what is sent ends up in a data property in the +page.svelte.
